# O jComboBox não atualiza os dados que já estão em um .txt

Tags: java

Eu tenho um campo de texto para pegar o nome das pessoas e um botão que salva esses nomes em um arquivo de texto, e eu tenho também um jCombobox, mas ele só mostra os dados que estão dentro do txt se eu clicar em Salvar. Eu queria que os dados aparecessem assim que eu abrisse a tela, sem a necessidade de clicar em salvar. Como recuperar esses dados que já estão dentro do txt e mostrar no combobox, logo que a tela é iniciada?

Imagem: quando eu abro a aplicação está exatamente assim. sem nada no combobox, sendo que já tem dados dentro do .txt. somente quando eu salvo um novo nome é que todos os dados do .txt aparecem.

[image: quando eu abro a aplicação está exatamente assim. sem nada no combobox, sendo que já tem dados dentro do .txt. somente quando eu salvo um novo nome é que todos os dados do .txt aparecem.]

```
package uploadexemplo;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    static java.io.File diretorio = new java.io.File("src/arquivo");
    boolean statusDir = diretorio.mkdir();
    public static String nomeDisciplina;
    ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList();
    public JButton btnSalvar;
    static FileReader fr;
    static String linha;
    static  BufferedReader br;
    static File arquivo = new File(diretorio, "ArquivoDisciplinas.txt");
    private static javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
    private static JTextField textField;

    public NewJFrame() {
        try {
            boolean statusArq = arquivo.createNewFile();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }

        initComponents();  
        btnSalvar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    salvar();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }   

    public static boolean Write(String Texto) {
        try {
            if (!arquivoExiste()) {
                arquivo.createNewFile();
            }
            FileWriter arq = new FileWriter(arquivo, true);
            PrintWriter gravarArq = new PrintWriter(arq);
            gravarArq.println(Texto);
            gravarArq.close();
            return true;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void salvar() throws IOException {
        fr = new FileReader(arquivo);  
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);  
        linha = br.readLine();
        String print = textField.getText() + ";";

        while(linha != null){
            jComboBox1.addItem(linha);
            linha = br.readLine();
        }
        if (NewJFrame.Write(print)) {
            System.out.println("Arquivo salvo com sucesso!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Erro ao salvar o arquivo!");
        }
    }

    public static boolean arquivoExiste() {
        return arquivo.exists();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initComponents() {
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setColumns(10);
        btnSalvar = new JButton("Salvar");
        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(19)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 149, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(textField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(35)
                            .addComponent(btnSalvar)))
                    .addContainerGap(171, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(23)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(textField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(btnSalvar))
                    .addGap(76)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(161, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira bem simples de fazer isso, é isolar parcialmente o código presente no método `salvar` em algum outro método, por exemplo `readText`:

```
private static void readText() throws IOException {
    fr = new FileReader(arquivo);  
    br = new BufferedReader(fr);  
    linha = br.readLine();

    jComboBox1.removeAllItems();

    while(linha != null){
        jComboBox1.addItem(linha);
        linha = br.readLine();
    }

    br.close();
}
```

Dessa forma, você tem um método somente com a responsabilidade de ler o arquivo e inserir os itens no combobox.

> *Obs.:* Adicione o método removeAllItems para evitar duplicar os itens já presentes no txt.

---

Agora basta chamar o novo método criado (readText) no método `salvar` após o a inserção da nova linha no txt, atualizando assim o combobox com o novo item:

```
public static void salvar() throws IOException {
    String print = textField.getText() + ";";

    if (NewJFrame.Write(print)) {
        System.out.println("Arquivo salvo com sucesso!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Erro ao salvar o arquivo!");
    }

    //Insere os itens no combobox
    readText();
}
```

Assim o código anterior continua funcionando e você tem um novo método que atualiza o combobox, então podemos chamar ele também no construtor da classe, após a criação dos itens de interface, pois ele precisa que o combobox já esteja instanciado:

```
public NewJFrame() {
    try {
        boolean statusArq = arquivo.createNewFile();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }

    initComponents();

    btnSalvar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                salvar();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    //Insere os itens no combobox
    try {
        readText();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
```

Com isso ao instanciar a classe NewJFrame, o txt já é lido e o combobox é criado de acordo com os valores presentes no txt.

Comment: Perfeito, Daniel Mendes! Só que ele tá permitindo salvar dois nomes iguais. Como eu faço para ele não permitir? obrigada

Comment: Você poderia ler o txt e verificar se o nome já existe em alguma linha antes de inserir o nome do txt, aí as regras você que dita, poderia comparar tudo em minúsculas por exemplo.

Comment: eu tentei isso dentro do método readText, mas não deu certo: `while (linha != null) {
   if (linha != print) {
    jComboBox1.addItem(linha);
    linha = br.readLine();
   }
  }`

Comment: Mas vc tem que tentar fazer dentro do método que salva. O read pelo que entendi não salva

Comment: O método que realmente salvar os dados no txt é o Write, então ele seria um candidato a ganhar essa validação, se não for ele, seria o método salvar.

Comment: Poxa, eu não consegui. Mas fico grata pela resposta anterior. Mas se quiser ajudar novamente, aguardo